# Spring Integration multiple transactional pollers with separate thread pools

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to implement a project for processing messages/events with the following requirements: an inbound message that comes in to the system should never be lost, even in the case of application crashes. When the processing either finishes successfully or fails, it should be logged for auditing purposes. These logs should also never be lost, even in the case of application crashes. It should also be reasonably performant.

I set up my project in the following way - I am using three Queue channels backed by a PostgreSQL message store. The main queue is used to store incoming messages, and its transactional poller will start the message flow. Transient errors are handled and retried inside the flow itself, using RetryAdvice, so if at any point the flow throws an exception, the transaction should not be rolled back, but instead the message should go to the error channel Queue which is also persistent. The error channel and success channel Queue also have transactional pollers setup in the same way.
Also to make it more performant, every transactional poller was set up with a fixed thread pool.

The problem with this setup is when the application runs the database connection timeouts:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
    at ...
```

Pollers are configured like this:

```
Pollers.fixedDelay(50).maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)
            .advice(
                TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                    .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                    .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
                    .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRED)
                    .transactionAttribute(object : DefaultTransactionAttribute() {
                        override fun rollbackOn(ex: Throwable): Boolean {
                            return false
                        }
                    })
                    .build()
            )
            .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

I tried playing around with fixedRate and maxMessagesPerPoll but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. When i remove the task executor the connection problem disappears but the performance is not great to say the least.
I suspect the performance issue is also related to the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query the poller is using to fetch new messages that blocks other threads until the flow is complete. Would it be feasible to configure the poller to use something like `SKIP LOCKED` as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fixedDelay(50)` is too fast to interact with DB. Since you have already `maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)`, there is no reason to look into DB so often. With that fast pace you really exhaust your connection pool, therefore the error you get.

With the `maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)` (which is default for `PollingConsumer`), all the records are fetched with one connection.

If `SKIP LOCKED` works for you, then indeed it is better to use it, since all those records in process are not going to be fetched and no transaction will wait for their `FOR UPDATE` to be unlocked.

You may also rethink the architecture to not use so many `QeueueChannel` against the same DB. You may have only one of them and process data in one transaction and same thread. The `maxMessagesPerPoll` might be as the size of connection pool.

The `TaskExecutor` is used for a single polling cycle, all the `maxMessagesPerPoll` are loaded in one thread, but since you use transactions, it might be the fact that a new connection is for each message from a pool.

**UPDATE**

I think sometime it is better to talk via code instead of trying to explain things using words. So, the whole logic about poller is here:

```
private Runnable createPoller() {
    return () ->
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
}
```

This `Runnable` is scheduled like this: `taskScheduler.schedule(createPoller(), this.trigger);`. So, every single time the `fixedDelay` triggers this method we got:

1. A task is executed on the other tread.
2. That task performs a loop until a polled message is null or we reach `maxMessagesPerPoll`.

The transaction you mentioned before is added around `doPoll()` which calls `receiveMessage()` and then `handleMessage(message)`. All that happens within a thread from that executor. And that thread is held until we reach `maxMessagesPerPoll`.

Typically we use a `taskExecutor` om a poller to free `TaskScheduler` for other work. But looks like you have a lot for the same Postgres DB, so that's where you fail: you just exhaust a connection pool with so many queries.

Comment: For the poller part, maxMessagesPerPoll determines how many messages will a single thread from the poller pool process.  So, if processing of one message takes ~100ms and with the thread pool set to 10 threads, fixedDelay set to 1000ms and `maxMessagesPerPoll` set to 10, one poller thread would be able to process roughly 10 messages per second, 100 messages per second for the whole pool. For the case when maxMessagesPerPoll is set to -1 this would always execute the poll and the whole flow in a single thread even if the pool is set, so it would process ~10 messages per second. Is this correct?

Comment: The reason I decided to have three Queue channels is to separate the main flow transaction (that is hitting an external service at the end) from the auditing transaction, so that auditing failures wouldn’t cause the main flow logic to be retried. Is there any other alternative inside Spring Framework to achieve this use case, apart from just processing them together in a single transaction? One idea might be to use Postgres subscribable channels instead of pollers so they don’t burden the connection pool, could it be used in the same transactional way with custom rollback?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. You may consider to use a bit slower fixedDelay for your auditing. You are limited by the resources of your connection pool with your current configuration.

Comment: And also: I hope you use `JdbcChannelMessageStore` with a `PostgresChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider` for those `QueueChannel` instances.